# The plugin Tflite uses a deprecated version of Android embedding

Tags: flutter, gradle-plugin, tflite

I have updated and **`tflite_flutter`** but still the gradle is not building.

```
tflite: ^1.1.2
tflite_flutter: ^0.9.1
```

The following this the **`error message`** I'm getting:

> The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android
> embedding.
>
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to
> see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise,
> consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove
> these deprecated APIs.
>
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the
> plugin to the V2 embedding:
> https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
>
> main.dart:1
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> * Where:
>
> Build file
> 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle'
> line: 24

I have gone through the docs, but I don't still understand what I need to do, Can someone please give a step by steps explanation regarding this issue.

Here is the **`Github repo`** on which I'm working: https://github.com/LoftyDroid/Plant-Disease-Detection-Flutter.git

you can try running this on your own PC to check if the solution is working or not and I don't mind contributions if you can.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using tflite: ^1.1.2, try replacing the files according to this pull request [PR #230](https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/pull/230/files)